# PdhOpenQuery eror в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <pdh.h>
#include <pdhmsg.h>
static HQUERY hQuery;
PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery);
```

Все привет. После отладки в qt вылетает ошибка “undefined reference to `PdhOpenQuery@12’ “

Помогите, кто встречался с этой ошибкой. Не могу понять, что ему не хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, не подключена соответствующая библиотека libpdh, в которой лежит тело функции PdhOpenQuery. Если вы работаете с Qt и пользуетесь проектными файлами .pro, то в этот проектный файл нужно добавить

```
LIBS += -lpdh
```

Возможно, придётся прописать ещё и путь к библиотеке, если она лежит в нестандартном месте:

```
LIBS += -L<путь\к\библиотеке>
```